Edit table cell using modal with Jquery
I've recently been trying to learn to use Jquery. I am trying to change cells in a table using Bootstrap modal and JQuery. I have succeeded in getting data from table to modal. The problem I encountered was when I wanted to update data from modal to the table. here is my script:
    $(document).on("click", "#edit-btn", function () {
        $('#editProductModal').modal('show');
        $tr =$(this).closest('tr');
        var data= $tr.children("td").map(function(){
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();
        $('#edit_no').val(data[0]);
        $('#edit_orderuid').val(data[1]);
        $('#edit_productname').val(data[2]);
        $('#edit_qty').val(data[3]);
        $('#edit_weight').val(data[5]);
        $('#edit_price').val(data[6]);
        $('#edit_discount').val(data[7]);
    });


//Update
$(document).on("click", "#update-product", function () {
    var data= $tr.children("td").map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    $(data[3]).text($('edit_qty').val())
    $('#editProductModal').modal('hide');

});

when I tried it the cell did not change. can you tell me where the problem is?


I think data[3] will not return you the element. you need to grab html element (td). 2. you forgot # before edit_qty


without seeing the HTML it is more or less a guess but I assume that you have multiple button with the same id edit-btn. Turn it into a class if it is so since id are unique in dom. If you have multiple element with the same id only one of them (the first occurrence) will work

which code block are you having the problem with? The edit-btn click or the update-product click? And which selector are you expecting to change?

also, have you tried to console.log data variable to see what it is returning?

@bprdev update-product, i try to change qty at cell 3

@TheUnderdog: If you're not familiar with your browser's debugging tools, now is a great time to start.  When you place a breakpoint in the script debugger to step through the operation(s) which aren't doing what you expect, which specific operation first produces an unexpected result?  While debugging, what observed data is used in that operation?  It's not clear to me which code segment above you're even specifically referring to.

@TheUnderdog ok, is edit_qty an ID or Class name? I think it is missing the # symbol. (credit goes to CodeThing for spotting that potential issue first)

Thank you to all of you. I have found the problem. I forgot to add '#' to edit_qty, looked at the result in console.log and changed it to var data = $tr.children("td"). really dumb beginner. I was really helped by your suggestions

@TheUnderdog glad you got it fixed. Next, you should start learning about const and let. We aren't using var anymore. That's unrelated to your post though. Just offering some extra help. Here is an article about it: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/

Please don't learn jQuery in 2024. Just do it with real javascript, you'll be much happier and better prepared for future work if you avoid that path altogether.
To answer your question though, in your update function add a breakpoint or log the value of data to the console and you'll see that it's an array of strings instead of an array of DOM element references. It should just be var data = $tr.children("td"), then when using data[3] you'll be able to set the value of that node

I have tried your suggestion and it works. I think I should use the console log more to find where the problem is. Thank You

You're welcome, yes it's handy as a quick window into what's going on. As code complexity grows, adding a breakpoint is better so that you can track what's happening

Yes, the console will be your primary debugging tool. At work, as a Web Developer, I use it all day long. When I am troubleshooting, I set up many console.log() at various points so that I can see things like: which code is triggered, what the data looks like, errors, etc.

While the other answer is correct, you could create a mapping array and simplify your work, like
    let modalMap = ['edit_no', 'edit_orderuid', 'edit_productname', 'edit_qty', 'edit_weight', 'edit_price', 'edit_discount'];

and then use it like
    $(document).on("click", "#edit-btn", function () {
        $('#editProductModal').modal('show');
        $tr =$(this).closest('tr');
        var data = $(this).closest('tr').children("td");
        for (let index = 0; index < modalMap.length; index++) {
            $("#" + modalMap[index]).val(data[index]);
        }
    });

and
//Update
$(document).on("click", "#update-product", function () {
    var data= $(this).closest('tr').children("td");
    $(data[data.indexOf("edit_qty")]).text($('#edit_qty').val());
    $('#editProductModal').modal('hide');

});

